# MS SQL query compare two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables `local1` and `local2` with common unique field **`id`**.
Both tables have different number of rows.

I need to find the difference between the two tables. How can I achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What form do you want differences in? E.g. tables of ids in only one table or the other, tables including the other columns of their tables. Do `local1` and `local2` have the same columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **`FULL JOIN`** between two tables and return only the rows that have **id** as **`NULL`**

```
SELECT Local1.*, [Local2].*
FROM Local1
    FULL JOIN Local2 ON (Local1.id = Local2.id)
WHERE Local1.id IS NULL OR Local2.id IS NULL
```